# Tag friends with Facebook API (Objective c)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I tag friends with Facebook graph API? I need it in two scenarios:

1. When I publish CheckIn I want to tag a friend with it.
2. When I publish to Feeds I want to tag a friend with it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/

field: **tags**, "The users the author tagged in the checkin", permission: `user_checkins`, array of objects containing the id and name fields

From http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/, There was a way to do it in the message field.  This is the format you want `@[{user_id}:1:{name}]`.  But it appears this way is either broken or the functionality removed.

Comment: I tested it yesterday.  It tagged a checkin with some of my friends.