# Facebook iOS SDK: Tagging friends?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Alright, there's a bunch of confusing / conflicting information about whether it's possible to tag people in posts that you make .. so I was wondering what the latest on this is? The docs say that we need to send an array of objects each with `id` and `name` params set to the user you'd like to tag, but when I send that request out, I get an error message that says this:

```
Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)" UserInfo=0x79bf5b0 {error=<CFBasicHash 0x79bca80 [0x1740b48]>{type = mutable dict, count = 3,
entries =>
    2 : <CFString 0x7989260 [0x1740b48]>{contents = "type"} = <CFString 0x79be240 [0x1740b48]>{contents = "OAuthException"}
    3 : <CFString 0x79b55a0 [0x1740b48]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x79b7f90 [0x1740b48]>{contents = "(#114) An id must be a valid ID string (e.g., "123")"}
    6 : <CFString 0x79bde00 [0x1740b48]>{contents = "code"} = 114
}
}
```

I've double checked that the id itself is valid. Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks, 
Teja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348624/tag-friends-with-facebook-api-objective-c) a lot a few months ago, I founded some posts that says it's possible with adding `@[{user_id}:1:{name}]` to the post, but eventually nothing worked. I suppose Facebook block this option in some point.
For now I'm pretty sure it's not possible, but I would be very happy to proved wrong here...

Comment: Ah, too bad. I wonder why they wouldn't update the docs for something as simple as this. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Using Facebook Open Graph actions you can tag friends. Look here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#taggingpeople

Answer (score 2):

**It's not possible to tag people in posts that you make through your iOS app on Facebook.**

**Facebook deactivated this feature for posts made via API long time ago**